# google drive api v3 create folder fails silently

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-js-client

After successfully authenticating via OAuth with full scope:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`
```

I create a folder according to the example in [Creating a folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder#creating_a_folder)

```
   var fileMetadata = {
        'name' : name,
        'mimeType' : 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
//        'parents': [ parent ]
    };
   gapi.client.drive.files.create({
       resource: fileMetadata,
       fields: 'id'
    }, function(err, file) {
      if(err) {
        // Handle error
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log('Folder Id: ', file.id);
        return file.id;
      }
    });
```

The callback function is never invoked, no error in the console.

How can i find out what's going on?

Comment: Are you running under node or in a browser? If a browser you can use the console/network tab to see the actual http traffic.

Comment: In the browser. The method call does not generate any network request.
Other methods work fine.
Is there an unminified version of the `api.js` i could debug into?

Comment: you mean gapi.js? Sadly not which is why I don't use it. The Drive API is a clean REST implementation so it's very easy to use from JS without using a library.

Comment: I mean the official javascript lib from https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/js
which makes the auth step a breeze. The rest, not so much :-/

Comment: I agree. I use the Google lib for OAuth because that does some iframe magic. Once I have the Access Token, I construct my own Drive REST calls. That way I can easily use Observers, Promises, async/await, etc.

Answer (score 5):

I've ended up using the lower level `gapi.client.request` method, which works reliably.

```
var body= {"name": name, 
           "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
           "parents": [parent.id]}

gapi.client.request({
  'path': 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/',
  'method': 'POST',
  'body': body
}).then(function(jsonResp,rawResp) {
    console.log(jsonResp)
    if (jsonResp.status==200) {
      callback(jsonResp.result)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `gapi.client.drive.files.create({...})` returns a promise, so don't pass a callback function, but instead use a `.then()` block to execute the promise.

```
var fileMetadata = {
    'name': FILE_NAME,
    'mimeType': FILE_MIME_TYPE,
    // 'parents': [ parentFolderID ]
};

gapi.client.drive.files.create({
    resource: fileMetadata,
    fields: '*'
}).then(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 200) {
        var file = response.result;
        console.log(file);
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
);
```