# gapi.client.drive.files.create does not work

Tags: google-api

I'm writing a vue app. I read [this sample code](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/appdata) and wrote code like this:

```
const apiKey = 'mykey';
const discoveryDocs = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest"]
const clientId = 'myclientid'
const scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata'

function handleClientLoad() {
    gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
}

function initClient() {
    gapi.client.init({
        apiKey,
        discoveryDocs,
        clientId,
        scope: scopes
    }).then(function () {
        createFile()
    });
}

function createFile() {
    console.log('createFile')
    var fileMetadata = {
        'name': 'config.json',
        'parents': ['appDataFolder']
    };
    var media = {
        mimeType: 'application/json',
        body: "body"
    };
    gapi.client.drive.files.create({
        resource: fileMetadata,
        media,
        fields: 'id'
    }, function (err, file) {
        console.log('function in createFile')
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            console.log('Folder Id:', file.id);
        }
    });
}
window.onload=handleClientLoad()
```

In the console, 'createFile' is logged but 'function in createFile' is not logged, so I think `function(err, file)...` does not work.

What is wrong?

I want the sample code to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The function `create()` returns a promise, to execute the request, it seems to need a then(). [See also this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63739412)

The example code though does not work since you will get a `403 The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file` error. This seems to happen since example code will create the file not in `appDataFolder` but in the root directory.

I managed to get it to work using the following code. Putting all request parameters flat into the object passed to `create()` seems to do the trick.

```js
        const s = new Readable();
        s.push("beep"); // the string you want
        s.push(null);

        gapi.client.drive.files
          .create({
            name: "config.json",
            parents: ["appDataFolder"],
            mimeType: "application/json",
            upload_type: "media",
            fields: "id",
            body: s,
          })
          .then(function (response) {
            if (response.status === 200) {
              var file = response.result;
              console.log(file);
            }
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.error(error);
          });
```